# Managing custom fields in appcelerator portal

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow

When i log into the arrowdb on the appcelerator portal i can go into the "manage data" and click down to a specific user object.

I wish to edit a "custom field" in a User object.

Previously in ACS all the custom fields were available for edit, but now in arrowdb i cannot even see the custom fields only add new. If i add a new custom field for a custom field that should already exist it seems to change the value. However i want to be able to see the values too.

Am i doing something wrong? Should i edit the user object somewhere else?

Comment: Hi Emil, this might make a great feature request. Stack Overflow is [not the right place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) for that. Please check if it has already been requested at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it has not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide a complete description in the ticket. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Yes maybe I should do that! I ended up building my own web for it using the REST api for arrowdb. Need more features too for my app (administration part) so I had to do this anyways.

Comment: Link to jira ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3810